# How to align images side by side in html?

Tags: html, css

I have three images with text and headers I want them at the same row side by side. I'm trying to use float left for that but after hundreds of attempts, I failed.

```
<section class="boxes">

   <div class="box">
     <img src="img/brush.png">
     <h2>graphic desigen</h2>
     <p>Curabitur nec ultrices ex.  
   </dive>

   <div class="box">
     <img src="img/html.png">
     <h2>html 5 marckup</h2>
     <p>Curabitur nec ultrices ex.  
   </dive>     

   <div class="box">
     <img src="img/css.png">
     <h2>graphic desigen</h2>
     <p>Curabitur nec ultrices ex. 
   </div>          

</section>
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at how a framework like Bootstrap handles it. https://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: You should also include the CSS for the example HTML you gave.

Answer (score 2):

The issue you have is not the images - its the divs - these are block level elements - so in order to align them in a horizontal row - you need to make them `display: inline-block` with CSS

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 33%;
  text-align: center
  }
  
  h2 { 
  font-size: 18px;
  }
  
    p { 
  font-size: 14px;
  }
```

```html
<section class="boxes">
  <div class="box">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/e5/3c/fb/e53cfb282846313a69daf9755bfaf339.jpg" width="150">
    <h2>graphic desigen</h2>
     <p>Curabitur nec ultrices ex.  
   </div>
   <div class="box">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/e5/3c/fb/e53cfb282846313a69daf9755bfaf339.jpg"  width="150">
    <h2>html5 markup</h2>
    <p>Curabitur nec ultrices ex.  
   </div>     
   <div class="box">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/e5/3c/fb/e53cfb282846313a69daf9755bfaf339.jpg"  width="150">
    <h2>graphic desigen</h2>
    <p>Curabitur nec ultrices ex. 
   </div>
</section>
```

Although this works - the newer way of showing images and associated headings / captions - is the HTML 5 figure element. This houses the image element and the figcaption element together

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align:center;
  max-width: 32%;
  
  }
  
  figcaption {
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  }
  
  h2 { 
  font-size: 12px;
  }
  
    p { 
  font-size: 14px;
  }
```

```html
<section class="boxes">
  <div class="box">
    <figure>
       <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/e5/3c/fb/e53cfb282846313a69daf9755bfaf339.jpg" width="100" />
       
    <figcaption>
      <h2>graphic desigen</h2>
       <p>Curabitur nec ultrices ex.</p>
    </figcaption>
   </figure>
 </div>

  <div class="box">
    <figure>
       <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/e5/3c/fb/e53cfb282846313a69daf9755bfaf339.jpg" width="100" />
       
    <figcaption>
      <h2>html 5 marckup</h2>
       <p>Curabitur nec ultrices ex.</p>
    </figcaption>
   </figure>
 </div>
   <div class="box">
    <figure>
       <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/e5/3c/fb/e53cfb282846313a69daf9755bfaf339.jpg" width="100" />
       
    <figcaption>
      <h2>graphic desigen</h2>
       <p>Curabitur nec ultrices ex.</p>
    </figcaption>
   </figure>
 </div>
   

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use CSS flex to achieve similar UI.

```css
.boxes {
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
}

p {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<section class="boxes">
  <div class="box">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/e5/3c/fb/e53cfb282846313a69daf9755bfaf339.jpg" width="150">
    <h2>graphic desigen</h2>
    <p>Curabitur nec ultrices ex.
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/e5/3c/fb/e53cfb282846313a69daf9755bfaf339.jpg" width="150">
    <h2>html5 markup</h2>
    <p>Curabitur nec ultrices ex.
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/e5/3c/fb/e53cfb282846313a69daf9755bfaf339.jpg" width="150">
    <h2>graphic desigen</h2>
    <p>Curabitur nec ultrices ex.
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hate to add yet another version, but even more I hate non-responsive design with absolute "px" units.

The following example will nicely fill any page width, and will adjust to resizing:

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; border-collapse: collapse; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
figure, aside { border-style: solid; border-width: .05em; margin-left: 2%; page-break-inside: avoid; }
figure img, aside img { width: 100%; height: auto; }
figcaption { text-align: center; }
figcaption>div { font-size: 110%; font-weight: bold; }

.boxes figure { display: inline-block; width: 30%; }
```

```html
<section class="boxes">
    <figure>
        <img alt="cat1" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTEcI.jpg" />
        <figcaption>
            <div>graphic design</div>
            Curabitur nec ultrices ex.
        </figcaption>
    </figure><figure>
        <img alt="cat2" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTEcI.jpg" />
        <figcaption>
            <div>html 5 markup</div>
            Curabitur nec ultrices ex.
        </figcaption>
    </figure><figure>
        <img alt="cat3" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTEcI.jpg" />
        <figcaption>
            <div>graphic design</div>
            Curabitur nec ultrices ex.
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
</section>
```

Note that using `<figure>` and `<figcaption>` will improve search engine results.  These tags tell the search engine that the caption belongs with the image.  But with generic `<div>` tags, the search engine can only guess.